# Making responsive DoubleClick ads refresh on browser resize

Tags: window-resize, google-dfp

I'm using [jquery.dfp.js](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/tree/master) to implement DoubleClick ad on a website. Pretty straightforward.

I used this to initialize the script:

```
$('selector').dfp({
dfpID:'xxxxxxxxx',
sizeMapping: {
    'my-default': [
        {browser: [1024, 768], ad_sizes: [980, 185]},
        {browser: [ 980, 600], ad_sizes: [[728, 90], [640, 480]]}
        {browser: [   0,   0], ad_sizes: [88, 31]}
    ],
  }  

});
```

And I'm using this to refresh the ads upon browser resize:

```
var resizeTimer;
function resizer(){        
    $('selector').dfp({
         dfpID:'xxxxxxxxx'
    });                                                           
}
window.addEventListener("resize",function(){         
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);        
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizer,250);
});
```

Everything seems to be working (Check out the leaderboard ad unit in the header area on [blog.insurancenewsnet.com](http://blog.insurancenewsnet.com)). One issue is that it refreshes every time a resize the browser window, so the ad flickers.

I have two questions.

- Is the way I'm refreshing the ads the best way to handle this?
- Is there a way to refresh the ads based on breakpoints instead of on every window resize?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.